# Count Number of Observations in Each Group

Tags: r, count

Keep getting the error message:

no applicable method for 'summarise_' applied to an object of class "character"
Traceback:

I've attempted to change the 'count = ' to:

(count = count(forest_cover$Cover_Type))
count = count(Cover_Type)

````
library(ggplot2)

# # forest_cover data is supplied to group_by() function to group the data based on Cover_Type. 
# # This 7 groups of data formed above is supplied as input to summarize() where we are getting the 
# # count of observations stored in the variable count. cover_type_ratio is created to store the 
# # ratio of cover type. 

coverType_count = forest_cover %>%  
  group_by(Cover_Type) %>%    # data is grouped according to labels (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) of cover type
  dplyr::summarize(count = count(forest_cover$Cover_Type)) %>%  # count the number of observations in each group
  mutate(cover_type_ratio=count/sum(count)) # divide the counts obtained in above step to get the ratio.

# # Display the contents of the variable coverType_count
coverType_count ```

I expect the code to plot a bar graph for the observations of each Cover_Type.
````

Answer (score 2):

`count` expects a `tibble/data.frame` and it is not used inside `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
forest_cover %>%
   count(Cover_Type) %>%
   dplyr::mutate(cover_type_ratio = n/sum(n))
```

---

If we want to use `summarise`, after `group_by`, then get the count with `n()`

```
forest_cover %>%
   group_by(Cover_Type) %>%
   dplyr::summarise(Count = n()) %>%
   dplyr::mutate(cover_type_ratio = Count/sum(Count))
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
# Count by the group: 

forest_cover$count <- ave(forest_cover$Cover_Type, forest_cover$Cover_Type, FUN = length)

# Calculate the ratio:

forest_cover$cover_type_ratio <- forest_cover$count/nrow(forest_cover)
```